# Need to change a macro so that it transposes and fills rows instread of columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a macro that copies, finds next available column along and then pastes as values.

After reluctantly continuing to do it in columns I have realized how much it easier it will be to have it vertically stored - data is pulled in every hour so having it in columns is making summarizing a lot of effort.

The macro below finds the next available column and then pastes next to it. I have tried to change it so that it will transpose paste with the date alongside the row in column A for example, but I am struggling to work it out.

Any help would be appreciated thanks a lot.

```
Sub HistoricalDataNewOne()
Dim TargetSht As Worksheet, SourceSht As Worksheet, SourceCol As Integer, SourceCells As Range

'If an error occurs skip code to the Err-Hanlder line and the display the error message.
On Error GoTo Err_Handler

'This is the sheet where your copy information from. Change "Sheet1" to the name of your soure sheet
Set SourceSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BARGE LIVE TRACKING")

'Name of the sheet where data is to be copied to. Rename Sheet2 to the name of your target sheet
Set TargetSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Detailed Tracking")

'This is the cells you will copy data from. This is targeting cells B1 to the last used cell in column B
Set SourceCells = SourceSht.Range("g3:h" & SourceSht.Range("J65536").End(xlUp).Row)

'This is finding the next column available in the target sheet. It assumes dates will be in row 1 and data in row 2 down
If TargetSht.Range("A1").Value = "" Then
    'Cell A1 is blank so the column to put data in will be column #1 (ie A)
    SourceCol = 1
ElseIf TargetSht.Range("IV1").Value <> "" Then
    'Cell IV1 has something in it so we have reached the maximum number of columns we can use in this sheet.
    'Dont paste the data but advise'
    MsgBox "There are no more columns available in the sheet " & TargetSht.Name, vbCritical, "No More Data Can Be Copied"
    'stop the macro at this point
    Exit Sub
Else
    'cell A1 does have data and we havent reached the last column yet so find the next available column
    SourceCol = TargetSht.Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column + 2
End If

'Put in the date in the appropriate column in row 1 of the target sheet
TargetSht.Cells(1, SourceCol).Value = Format(Now, "HH:MM DD/MMM")

'We can now start copying data. This will copy the cells in column B from the source sheet to row 2+ in the target sheet
SourceCells.Copy
TargetSht.Cells(2, SourceCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Exit Sub 'This is to stop the procedure so we dont display the error message every time.

Err_Handler:
MsgBox "The following error occured:" & vbLf & "Error #: " & Err.Number & vbLf & "Description: " & Err.Description, _
        vbCritical, "An Error Has Occured", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These amendments to the last part should do:

```
Sub HistoricalDataNewOne()
    Dim TargetSht As Worksheet, SourceSht As Worksheet, SourceCells As Range

    'If an error occurs skip code to the Err-Hanlder line and the display the error message.
    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    'This is the sheet where your copy information from. Change "Sheet1" to the name of your soure sheet
    Set SourceSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BARGE LIVE TRACKING")

    'Name of the sheet where data is to be copied to. Rename Sheet2 to the name of your target sheet
    Set TargetSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Detailed Tracking")

    'This is the cells you will copy data from. This is targeting cells B1 to the last used cell in column B
    Set SourceCells = SourceSht.Range("g3:h" & SourceSht.Range("J65536").End(xlUp).Row)

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' No changes so far
    ' Now the changes:
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim dstRow As Long: dstRow = TargetSht.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row + 2

    'Put in the date in the appropriate row columns A 1 of the target sheet
    TargetSht.Cells(dstRow, 1).Value = Format(Now, "HH:MM DD/MMM")
    TargetSht.Cells(dstRow, 2).Resize(SourceCells.Columns.Count, SourceCells.Rows.Count).Value2 = _
        Application.Transpose(SourceCells.Value2)

    Exit Sub 'This is to stop the procedure so we dont display the error message every time.

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "The following error occured:" & vbLf & "Error #: " & Err.Number & vbLf & "Description: " & Err.Description, _
            vbCritical, "An Error Has Occured", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext

End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks so much for your response! Just one thing - at the moment it only pastes column G. Do you know what to add to make it paste/transpose G and H? thanks so much

Comment: I can't seem to fix it so it pastes 2 rows, your help is much appreciated! thank you

Comment: @elliotfrost you are welcome :). I already corrected that  since you tried it, did you retry the last edited version?